# Parsing HTML DOM with PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, html-parsing

I want to read records from the following HTML into variables, using PHP. What is the best way to do this? The example HTML represents two records.

Result for record 1:

```
    rank = 1
    tag = LLG8V2QQ
    name = Pat
    level = 11
    league = 1
    trophies = 4154
    donations = 578
    role = Elder
```

```
  <div class="clan__rowContainer">
    <div class="clan__row">
                        #1
                </div>
    <div class="clan__row">
      <a class="ui__blueLink" href='/profile/LLG8V2QQ'>Pat</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clan__row">
      <span class="clan__playerLevel">11</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clan__row">
      <div class="clan__leagueContainer">
                        <div class="league__1"></div>
                    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clan__row">
      <div class="clan__cup">4154</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clan__row">578</div>
    <div class="clan__row">
         Elder
                </div>
  </div>


  <div class="clan__rowContainer">
    <div class="clan__row">
                        #2
                </div>
    <div class="clan__row">
      <a class="ui__blueLink" href='/profile/299GGR2J'>Erikson</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clan__row">
      <span class="clan__playerLevel">11</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clan__row">
      <div class="clan__leagueContainer">
                        <div class="league__1"></div>
                    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clan__row">
      <div class="clan__cup">4081</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clan__row">248</div>
    <div class="clan__row">
         Member
                </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can consider [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Answer (score 1):

My code so far:

```
    <?php 
        $_document = implode('', file('http://myURL')); 

        $dom = new DomDocument; 
        $dom->loadHTML($_document); 
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
        $divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div'); 
        foreach ($divs as $div) {
            $class = $div->getAttribute('class');
            if ($class == 'clan__rowContainer') {
                NO IDEA WHAT NOW
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using PHP's DOMDocument class. Here's the documentation [link](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) .
You can for examle start with:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("filename.html");
//or $doc->loadHTML("<html><body>Test<br></body></html>");
```

then iterate over doc nodes and their children:

```
foreach ($doc->childNodes as $item) {
    //... some code
}
```